# Why Wmi info for disk size is wrong?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization, wmi, partition

i am expecting a very curious problem. In a script collecting disk infos on a list of W2008 servers, i realize that, for some servers, the Wmi info for the disk size is wrong.

My Powershell command: `Get-WmiObject win32_LogicalDisk`. For one partition, it returns 70Go of disk size, but 100 Go of FreeSpace... When i right-click the partition in the explorer, the disk size is 70Go, and the Freespace is 69,5Go.
But... in the Disk Management, the partition size is 102Go...
Maybe there is a problem with the performance counters but i don't know what to do...

What i have tried:

- get disk info via wmi, fsutil and "explorer" : wrong infos.
- get disk info via Disk Management, and the diskpart utility : good infos.
- chkdsk /x q: : no changes.
- with dispart.exe, on the volume Q: : `extend filesystem`. No changes.
- Reset the performance counters.

Any idea?

Some screen captures:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please include links to screenshots of the Explorer and disk management windows.

Comment: Make sure you have backups of any data on the drive. Then run `chkdsk /x Q:` and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I've tried `chkdsk` but nothing changes. I also tried the diskpart.exe utility with the `extend filesystem` command. Nothing.

Comment: Have a look at this blog article and see if it helps you out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2008/07/03/ntfs-misreports-free-space.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this article. But in my case, it is the partition size which is different in the explorer and in the disk management UI. The used space is the same, so i guess that freespace is just a substraction depending the partition size.