# Wrong size listed in disk management

Tags: windows-server-2008

As you can see in the attached screenshot, the disk management reports an incorrect disk size.
However, the disk properties window reports the correct disk size.

[image]

As a result I cannot upgrade my Windows 2008 server because the windows installer complains that there is not enough disk space available.

This Windows server 2008 runs inside a VMware virtual machine.

How can I fix this?

EDIT 1: Diskpart info
[image]

Comment: What does diskpart report the disk space to be?

Comment: Did you extend the disk in VMWare?

Comment: @Drifter104 Just updated my question and added what diskpart reports

Comment: @Reaces There is no need to extend the disk. In VMware the disk size is set to 500GB

Comment: @YiannisMpourkelis If you extended the disk size in VMWare recently, this is a known possible bug. Hence why I asked. See for example [this kb](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/832316).

Comment: @Reaces No, I did not extended the disk size.

Comment: I've seen strange numbers with disk quotas in the past (not exactly like this) but can you check the quota tab to see if there are any set?

Comment: Capacity looks the same, freespace does not. See http://serverfault.com/questions/529296/why-wmi-info-for-disk-size-is-wrong and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2008/07/03/ntfs-misreports-free-space.aspx

Comment: @Drifter104 You are correct. The problem was that disk quotas where enabled. What I did to disable disk quotas was this: From command line I ran mmc.exe , went to  > file > Add/remove Snap-in > Local computer policy. Then went to Local computer policy > Computer configuration > Administrative templates > System > Disk quotas > Enable disk quotas > Set to Disabled. Please add this as a reply to accept your answer as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk Quotas will show different amounts depending how and what is set.

(As per comment) These can be disabled doing the following

Run mmc.exe
Add/remove Snap-in (Local computer policy).
Go To Local computer policy > Computer configuration > Administrative templates > System > Disk quotas > Enable disk quotas > Set to Disabled.